# React variable into html input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have in my .js a React variable `this.status.result` which holds my value (it's refreshing and changing values.

I want to put it in my html code, but I have no idea how to do it. I want something like this:

```
    <div id="demo-container"></div>
    <script src="bundle_test.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <form method="post">
    <input type="text" value=this.status.result>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Is there any easy solution? I know I can create a form with React, but for my project won't work.

EDIT: .js file has more than 25k lines.

Comment: Does this one `value={this.status.result}` work ?

Comment: Works like plain text

Comment: So what are you expecting? `result` hold an HTML and you want to re-render it inside input?

Comment: It is a qr code scanner, this.status.result holds a scanned value and I want to put this value into input (there are more than one input in multiple forms)

Comment: I think you have to add more details about your problem. `result` is an array, and how many `input` you want to render? What does it look like if you pass like others suggested `value = this.status.result` and what is your expect result? Otherwise it is very hard for us to guess your target.

Answer (score 1):

You should put { } when using variables in react js components:

```
  <input type="text" value={this.status.result}>
```

Comment: Works like plain text

Comment: can you paste whole code here i.e. react component code please

Comment: okay. All I want you to check that `this` exists in your code above and `<input>` should be inside `render`.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use the value of props in your html, you need to wrap the same in brackets like `{this.props.propName}`. For your code just make this change:

```
<div id="demo-container"></div>
<script src="bundle_test.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" value={this.status.result}>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the render function of your component:

```
render() {

    const result = this.status.result;

    return (
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" value={result}>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is it the only solution? It doesn't suits for me because of having multiple forms in my code which uses this.status.result so creating multiple forms in .js (instead in html) is not what I want

Comment: Thats the react way to render a component... you dont need a js file for every form, just render them as an array of forms.